# how to add products which can be ordered in any length

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

I need to create a system where the length is selectable by the user and then price is calculated on tubing.

The length ranges from 1m to 10m and can be ordered in 0.25 segments (i.e 3.75). It also has a colour option.

The length changes price and weight, colour changes nothing. I guess I can charge a fixed price for weight so maybe disregard this.

I've been reading about configrable products but dont think this is the answer because of the variations involved.

What are my options?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried custom options?

Comment: I have but I then need to add the same custom option on every product. Is there another way?